# How to get attribute value based on node value using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon

I am working on Orbeon forms and i have to use Xpath to retrieve attribute value. My scenario is as mentioned below.

I have a xml node as below.

```
<n>
<node>
<page id='1'>true</page>
<page id='2'>false</page>
<page id='3'>true</page>
<page id='4'>true</page>
<page id='5'>false</page>
<page id='6'>true</page>
</node>
</n>
```

Now when i pass any attribute value to xpath, it should return me the attribute value where it finds the next node having value 'true'. For example, if i pass id=1, then i should get the result as 3 since after , the next node having true is . Please note i must get only 3 and not 3,4 and 6.

I have tried something like the below, but i am not getting the expected result.

```
/n/node/page[@id>"1" and .='true']/@id
```

Extending my question:

Same case should apply if i give the last value and expect to have to next below attribute value having true. Example. If i give 6, xpath expression should give me 4. I dont mind if i have to use another xpath expression for this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you would like to get the first page with `@id` higher than 1 and content equal to `true`. Then the following will do the trick:

```
(/n/node/page[@id>"1" and .='true'])[1]/@id/string()
```

Compared to what you had, picking the "first item that matches…" is done with `(…)[1]`, and I use `/string()` at the end to get the value of the attribute. Depending on where you are using this expression, this won't be necessary as the attribute will be converted to a string for you.

Comment: Thanks Avernet. This one worked. And for second part of my question i used as below and worked fine. (/n/node/page[@id<'6' and .='true'])[last()]/@id

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
/n/node/page[@id>"1" and .='true']/@id[position() < 2]
```

extending my answer:

you can also use

```
/n/node/page[@id>"1" and .='true']/@id[last() - 1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I dont think postion() < 2 is the right expression here.